# Running images in rootless docker, images not showing up

Tags: docker, sudo, docker-image, rootless

I've configured rootles docker using [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/). Note to take: I've previously had docker installed with a bunch of images. When I tried to do `docker images` it showed no images. But when I do `sudo docker images` it shows the previously configured images I had before. Is it possible to actually see those "sudo docker images" in "docker images" and run it without using sudo?

Comment: Your rootless Docker isn't going to be able to see images (or containers, volumes, etc) that were created in root-full Docker. Because it's running under your user id, it has to store all its resources in a different location (to which it has write access).

Comment: So is it possible to migrate those images etc. to rootless docker without damaging them?

Comment: You could probably migrate images through an appropriate combination of `sudo docker image save` and `docker image load`. With a little shell scripting you might even be able to automate the process.